# Why does Scala compiler reject function body with no leading space?

Tags: scala

I found this very confusing.

```
scala> val a = (x:Boolean)=>!x
<console>:7: error: not found: value x
       val a = (x:Boolean)=>!x
                ^

scala> val a = (x:Boolean)=> !x
a: Boolean => Boolean = <function1>
```

The only difference between the two is the whitespace. Is it because the lexer considers `=>!` an operator?

Answer (score 6):

You're right, it's unable to parse the first version correctly. Here are differences in the trees it generates for the first and second options:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => u}
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe=>u}

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => m}
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror=>m}

scala> import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

scala> val tb = m.mkToolBox()
tb: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox[reflect.runtime.universe.type] = scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl@4426fc2e

scala> val treeNotWorking = tb.parse("(x:Boolean)=>!x")
treeNotWorking: tb.u.Tree = (x: Boolean).$eq$greater$bang(x)

scala> val treeWorking = tb.parse("(x:Boolean) => !x")
treeWorking: tb.u.Tree = ((x: Boolean) => x.unary_$bang)
```

As you can see, it tries to call the `=>!` on a boolean variable `x` defined elsewhere. For example, if we had `x` in the scope, we'd get a different error:

```
scala> val x = true
x: Boolean = true

scala> val a = (x:Boolean)=>!x
<console>:17: error: value =>! is not a member of Boolean
       val a = (x:Boolean)=>!x
```

Answer (score 2):

Scala does not reserve the symbol `=>!`:

```
scala> val =>! = 42
=>!: Int = 42
```

Any contiguous string of punctuation characters not reserved by the language is available for definition. If you want to define a symbol containing both punctuation and alphanumeric characters then you must place an underscore at every transition between punctuation and alphanumeric and vice versa. If it did not do this, a string of input characters such as `x+y` would be a single symbol (as it is, e.g., in Lisp).